# How to find unique words that are in category - Python

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a dataframe with a column1 that contains textual data, column2 contains the category of the text, contained in column1. I would like to find the words that occur in the textual data for one category (i.e. Informal), but do not occur in the other categories. Multiple rows in the dataframe will have the same category.

```
        Textual                           Category 
Hi johnny how are you today              Informal 
Dear Johnny                              Formal
Hey Johnny                               Informal
To Johnny                                Formal
```

Example Output:

```
Informal: [Hi, how, are, you, today, Hey]
Formal: [Dear, To]
```

Comment: You should look operation like "group by" on Dataframes:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Does your *actual* data contain punctuation etc? It has a habit of sticking to words, so that `split()` is the wrong tool.

Comment: No it doesn't contain punctuation

Answer (score 2):

```
# Remove punctuation
df.Textual = df.Textual.str.replace('.', '')
df.Textual = df.Textual.str.replace(',', '')
df.Textual = df.Textual.str.replace('?', '')

# get list of all words per Category
df1 = df.groupby(['Category'])['Textual'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
df1['Textual'] = df1.Textual.str.split().apply(lambda x: list(filter(None, list(set(x)))))
print(df1)

# Split the list in different columns
df = pd.DataFrame(df1.Textual.values.tolist(), index= df1.index)
print(df)

# Reshape the df to have a line for each word
df['Category'] = df1.Category
df = df.set_index("Category")
df = df.stack()
print(df)

# Drop word that are present in several Categories
df = df.str.upper().drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print(df)

# Reshape the df to the expected output
df = df.groupby('Category').apply(list)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary via `groupby` + `to_dict`. Then calculate unique values and remove them via `set` and a dictionary comprehension. Note, unlike your example, I don't apply any case checks, e.g. I assume Johnny will always have a capital J.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({'Textual': ['Hi Johnny how are you today', 'Dear Johnny', 'Hey Johnny', 'To Johnny'],
                   'Category': ['Informal', 'Formal', 'Informal', 'Formal']})

def return_unique(x):
    return list(set(' '.join(x.values).split()))

res = df.groupby('Category')['Textual'].apply(return_unique).to_dict()

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(res.values())).items()

unique = {k for k, v in c if v == 1}

res = {k: list(set(v) & unique) for k, v in res.items()}

{'Formal': ['To', 'Dear'],
 'Informal': ['today', 'how', 'Hi', 'Hey', 'are', 'you']}
```